# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when copying or retaining Block

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exc-bad-access, objective-c-blocks

As far as I understand a Block acts like an object, in that you can send copy or release messages to it, e.g:

```
[myBlock copy];
```

However whenever I do this, or release a block, I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

If I use the block functions, everything works as expected, e.g.:

```
Block_copy(myBlock);
```

I thought both ways of releasing and copying blocks were identical?

It's not that much of a problem, but it is a little annoying that if I have a property (copy) which is a Block, I have to write the setter method myself.

For example: With Properties:

```
//Header
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^cancelledBlock)(void);

//Implementation
@sythesize cancelledBlock;
```

leads to EXC_BAD_ACCESS when setting `cancelledBlock`

but if I do:

```
//Header
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^cancelledBlock)(void);

//Implementation
@sythesize cancelledBlock; //saves me doing the getter as well

- (void)setCancelledBlock:(void (^)(void))aCancelledBlock {
    if (cancelledBlock == aCancelledBlock) {
        return;
    }
    void (^oldValue)(void) = cancelledBlock;
    cancelledBlock = Block_copy(aCancelledBlock);
    Block_release(oldValue);

}
```

there is no EXC_BAD_ACCESS and everything runs as it should.

Comment: You should only release what you retained or copied previously.

Comment: I know that, as I say in my question trying to do `[myBlock copy]` gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS, but `Block_copy(myBlock)` doesn't

Comment: Can you show us a full example?

Comment: There aren't really examples, everywhere I use blocks it is the same.

Comment: Copied block properties work just fine. If they don't in your case, you should create and upload a simple demonstration project that we can try.

Comment: I just created a demo project, and it works fine in that. the project I'm working in now which has this problem was created in Xcode 3.2, before Xcode 4 and iOS5 (with ARC, maybe that makes a difference, I turned it off though in the demo project).

Comment: What compiler and IDE are you running into the issue with? If its GCC flip to Clang

Answer (score 26, accepted):

After a long and boring afternoon and evening I finally came across this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999238/exc-bad-access-on-objc-setassociatedobject-with-weak-library-usr-lib-libsystem/6191733#6191733), although it may seem unrelated, the chain of websites I visited to find it, creates that relation.

Basically I had to remove `-weak_library /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib` from the linker flags and replace it with `-weak-lSystem`.

Comment: Thank you, Jonathan! After after more than 4 hours you solved my problem!

Comment: Whoa. I have literally spent weeks trying to track down what was causing my app to crash when launching in the simulator. This answer did it. Thank you so much!

Comment: I know how annoying this problem is, I just wish I knew why this solution works.

Comment: I wish there is a donate system in SO so I could give you 1000 points for this answer. I am not sure whether I could have found the cause by myself in several long and boring afternoons.